# Product of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over a fixed field $k$. Under what circumstances do we have $V\times V\cong V$? I think this should be true if $\mathrm{dim} \ V=\infty$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Two vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension. What is the dimension of $V\times V$ in the terms of $V$ dimension?

Comment: Writing $\dim V = \infty$ is misleading. Vector spaces can have infinite dimensions of different sizes.

Comment: It may also only be a necessary condition. Because two vector spaces of infinite dimension need not be isomorphic.

Comment: @TheNumber23 These are not two arbitrary vector spaces!

Comment: Am i right to assume this is an external direct sum?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: o really? it is not misleading, it just means not finite

Comment: I think it is misleading because no vector space has dimension $\infty$. The dimension of a vector space is the cardinality of a basis for that vector space. The symbol $\infty$ is not used to express the cardinality of any set. Instead, I would say that the vector space is infinite dimensional and leave it at that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you know that $\dim_K V\times W=\dim_K V+\dim_K W$ for any two (finite dimensional) $K$-vector spaces $V,W$.

Then it is clear that if $V$ is finite dimensional we can't have $\dim V\times V=\dim V$, unless $V=0$.

But we *can* have $\dim V\times V=\dim V$ if $V$ is *not* finite dimensional: if $B\subset V$ is an infinite basis, then $|B|+|B|=|B|$, that is, there exists a bijection between the set $(B\times\{0\})\cup(\{0\}\times B)$ (which is in fact a basis in $V\times V$), and $B$ and this extends to an isomorphism of $K$-vector spaces between $V\times V$ and $V$.

Comment: the formula for the dim holds even if both are infinite dimensional innit?

Comment: @KarlKäfer Yes, of course! It follows from the definition of the sum of two cardinals.

Comment: how would you prove it without using AC? :D

Comment: @KarlKäfer The mathematics I know uses AC.